# When do you have to use PLSQL instead of SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know Oracle SQL quite well, but only know the very basics of PL/SQL. I recently had an interview where I was asked, "When do you use PL/SQL instead of SQL", and I was stumped. I didn't find a clear answer for this while researching. From what I have read so far, I think you use PL/SQL instead of Oracle SQL when you need to create things like functions, procedures, cursors, packages, types. Is that really the answer? Can you not create those things with Oracle SQL?

Thanks to anyone answering!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to know when someone writes a single SQL statement vs when someone needs to write Procedural Programming. A simple explanation would be:

1. A SQL statement is a single statement which would fulfill a specific
   need for a very specific component surrounding a reasonable number
   of tables/views that can be joined to each other.
2. But lets say you have to make a database application where you need
   to build processes for accumulating data, applying business logics
   for transactions happening in your front end application, making
   sure that constraints are intact by making use of triggers, cleaning
   data, matching data, combining multiple data sources, transformation
   of data, bringing data into different granularity, loading data in
   separate dimensional and fact tables, loading data into aggregate
   table, loading data into the DataWarehouse presentation layer etc.,
   that is when you would need to create stored procedure, functions,
   views, triggers to create the data pipeline which can support all
   these activities and workflow.
3. Know that these procedures, functions and triggers will have
   multiple such SQL statements which you are referring to along with
   conditional blocks, looping, temporary table, input and output
   variables, index creation steps etc.

Comment: index creation steps should typically not be part of a PL/SQL application.

Comment: You can definitely have overnight post data load Index Re-Creation stored procedure in your ETL process of Data Warehouse to recreate the indexes which were dropped prior to data load. But yes, it varies from organization to organization on how their DBAs maintain the indexes.

Comment: OK, ETL processes might be the exception that proves the rule.

Answer (score 1):

There are several key ways to use PL/SQL in addition to (or, on top of) SQL:

- Don't give app developers direct access to tables via SQL. Instead, build an API in PL/SQL packages. This will make it easier for appdevs especially UI folks like JavaScript developers to properly follow transactional, data integrity and security rules.
- Implement business rule logic in the database. Some of that can be done in "pure" SQL, but usually you will need a more procedural or OO language to do that. I know, I know - there is a big, never-ending debate about where to put biz logic. Here's how I look at it: if you put it in the database, close to the data and data model, you are (1) more likely to get the rules right and keep them in synch with the data model and (2) that logic is available from whatever front end, middle tier or backend process that needs it.

A comprehensive review of "Why Use PL/SQL?" is available [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/plsql-and-ebr/why-use-plsql).

Answer (score -3):

PL/SQL is Oracle's SQL dialect. If you're writing any Oracle specific stuff into your statements (like custom datatypes not covered by the SQL92 standard for example) you're writing PL/SQL.

But yes, usually people talk about PL/SQL in the context of stored procedures and things like that.

To summarise: Oracle SQL IS PL/SQL

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with most of what you said. It is not a *dialect*, it is a *language*. Procedures, functions, types, ... - these aren't *Oracle specific stuff*. Yes, people usually match PL/SQL with *stored procedures*. No, Oracle SQL is not PL/SQL.

Comment: Beat me to it, Littlefoot. :-) 

Perhaps this will help:

PL/SQL is to Oracle SQL
as
Transact-SQL is to Microsoft SQL